# How to call a function based on element position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to Javascript. I'm trying to make a style change based on an element's position on the screen, but I'm pretty clueless as to how to make it work.

What I'm trying to do is make the background of an element become fixed once the element has reached the top of the page (and return to being unset when you scroll back up). So far I ended up with this code but as you can tell it triggers only when you click it. My question being which event should I use to make it go into action once the user has simply scrolled up to the point I intended?

```
const page2 = document.getElementById("about");

page2.addEventListener("click", bgFixer);

function bgFixer() {
    rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top <= 0) {
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        document.head.appendChild(style);
        style.sheet.insertRule('.page-2{background-attachment: fixed}')
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! Just a reminder that I'm really new so the more detailed the explanations are the better.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as well?

Comment: What it sounds like you're suggesting is called scroll spying. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/zchee/pen/ogzvZZ

Comment: @zfrisch The entire thing or the specific element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the distance of the scroll by checking `scrollTop` of your containing element.

If the distance between the top of your "sticky" element and the `scrollTop` is 0 or less, fix the "sticky" element in place by adding a class with `position: fixed; top: 0px;`

Since the above changes the position of the "sticky" element, we want to store the original `top` distance so we know that, when the distance of `scrollTop` is less than that of the original `top` distance, we remove the class.

```
let el = document.querySelector.bind(document),

  c = el("#test"),
  t = el("#toTop");


c.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

  // get inner top distance
  let ttop = t.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  // get container scroll distance
  let ctop = c.scrollTop;

  // if the initial top distance isn't set, set it
  if (!this.init) this.init = ttop;

  // if the inner top is less than or equal to 0 ( no distance )
  // and the container scroll is greater than the initial top distance
  if (ttop <= 0 && ctop >= this.init) {

  // make fixed
    t.classList.add("stuck")
  } else {

  // remove fixed class
    t.classList.remove("stuck");
  }
});
```

```js
let el = document.querySelector.bind(document),

  c = el("#test"),
  t = el("#toTop");


c.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

  // get inner top distance
  let ttop = t.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  // get container scroll distance
  let ctop = c.scrollTop;

  // if the initial top distance isn't set, set it
  if (!this.init) this.init = ttop;

  // if the inner top is less than or equal to 0 ( no distance )
  // and the container scroll is greater than the initial top distance
  if (ttop <= 0 && ctop >= this.init) {
  
  // make fixed
    t.classList.add("stuck")
  } else {
  
  // remove fixed class
    t.classList.remove("stuck");
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

#test {
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#toTop::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px red;
}

#toTop {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 300px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#toTop.stuck {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

#after {
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="toTop">test</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Neque volutpat
    ac tincidunt vitae semper. Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar. Id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum
    integer. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. In fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus. Risus nullam eget felis eget.</p>

  <p>
    Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus
    mauris a. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in. Elementum pulvinar etiam
    non quam lacus suspendisse. Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie.
  </p>
  <p>
    Sed libero enim sed faucibus. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat. Ac turpis egestas
    integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis
    imperdiet proin fermentum. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Eu consequat ac felis donec et. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna
    id. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt.
  </p>
  <p>
    Laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Feugiat nibh
    sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit. Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Nam aliquam sem et
    tortor consequat id porta nibh. Sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Sed faucibus turpis in eu. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque
    sit. Dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a. Sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit. Risus at ultrices mi tempus. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Risus ultricies tristique nulla
    aliquet enim tortor. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus
    mauris a. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in. Elementum pulvinar etiam
    non quam lacus suspendisse. Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie.
  </p>
  <p>
    Sed libero enim sed faucibus. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat. Ac turpis egestas
    integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis
    imperdiet proin fermentum. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Eu consequat ac felis donec et. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna
    id. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt.
  </p>
  <p>
    Laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Feugiat nibh
    sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit. Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Nam aliquam sem et
    tortor consequat id porta nibh. Sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Sed faucibus turpis in eu. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque
    sit. Dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a. Sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit. Risus at ultrices mi tempus. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Risus ultricies tristique nulla
    aliquet enim tortor. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank! this really seems like it could be helpful in my case. I'll try applying it to my page and see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very easily now with `position: sticky;` it will change between `fixed` and `static` when it is at `top: 0;` defined only in CSS.

Learn more about sticky positioning: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

```css
 .top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis feugiat lacus. Etiam mollis odio ipsum, et lobortis dolor fermentum gravida. Praesent volutpat metus quis venenatis venenatis. Sed semper pharetra nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis egestas felis ac maximus iaculis. Nulla quis metus condimentum, porta mi sed, convallis risus. Nulla vehicula lorem elit, eu pulvinar velit pretium quis. Maecenas vitae pulvinar massa. Morbi congue erat vitae pharetra faucibus.</p>
  
<p class="top">top</p>
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis feugiat lacus. Etiam mollis odio ipsum, et lobortis dolor fermentum gravida. Praesent volutpat metus quis venenatis venenatis. Sed semper pharetra nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis egestas felis ac maximus iaculis. Nulla quis metus condimentum, porta mi sed, convallis risus. Nulla vehicula lorem elit, eu pulvinar velit pretium quis. Maecenas vitae pulvinar massa. Morbi congue erat vitae pharetra faucibus.</p>
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis feugiat lacus. Etiam mollis odio ipsum, et lobortis dolor fermentum gravida. Praesent volutpat metus quis venenatis venenatis. Sed semper pharetra nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis egestas felis ac maximus iaculis. Nulla quis metus condimentum, porta mi sed, convallis risus. Nulla vehicula lorem elit, eu pulvinar velit pretium quis. Maecenas vitae pulvinar massa. Morbi congue erat vitae pharetra faucibus.</p>
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis feugiat lacus. Etiam mollis odio ipsum, et lobortis dolor fermentum gravida. Praesent volutpat metus quis venenatis venenatis. Sed semper pharetra nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis egestas felis ac maximus iaculis. Nulla quis metus condimentum, porta mi sed, convallis risus. Nulla vehicula lorem elit, eu pulvinar velit pretium quis. Maecenas vitae pulvinar massa. Morbi congue erat vitae pharetra faucibus.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly helpful in my case. it's a landing page with 3 sections, each section has its own background image. All I want is the background image style property to change from unset to fixed, not fix the entire section to the top.